# Using PyQt5 to embed a dynamical bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I wrote the following code in python to show a bar chart in the GUI generated by `PyQt5`.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, \
QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QInputDialog, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QGridLayout,     QStackedLayout, QFormLayout
from  PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import time
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.lines import Line2D

import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as     NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# data
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import os
import csv

#define  the path to data
pathToData='C:/RC/python/data/'
dataName= '31122017ARB.csv'
# import 
data=pd.read_csv(pathToData+dataName, delimiter=';',encoding='cp1252')


# percent  MW
data['MWP']=data[' MW ']/sum(data[' MW '])
#aggregate by   Best
datag=data.groupby('Best', as_index=False).agg({'MW': 'sum'})
x=["BE"+s for s in[str(s) for s in [int(x) for x in datag.iloc[:,0].tolist()]]]
y=datag.ix[:,1].tolist()




figure = plt.figure()

H = np.array([[100, 2, 39, 190], [402, 55, 369, 1023], [300, 700, 8, 412], [170, 530, 330, 1]])
Z = np.array([[3, 290, 600, 480], [1011, 230, 830, 0], [152, 750, 5, 919], [340, 7, 543, 812]])


class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # a figure instance to plot on
        self.figure = plt.figure()

        # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
        # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init_
        self.im = None
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press_event)

        # this is the Navigation widget
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.plot)
        self.timer.setInterval(5000)

        # Just some button connected to `plot` method
        self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.timer.start)
        self.button.setDefault(False)

        self.stop = QPushButton("Stop")
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.timer.stop)
        self.stop.setDefault(False)

        self.exit = QPushButton('Exit')
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.exit.setDefault(True)

         layout = QFormLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        layout.addWidget(self.stop)
        layout.addWidget(self.exit)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.lb = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        self.lb.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.ToolTip)

            def plot(self):
        self.x  = ["BE"+s for s in[str(s) for s in [int(x) for x in datag.iloc[:,0].tolist()]]]
        self.y  = datag.iloc[:,1].tolist()#np.sin(self.x)

        self.setWindowTitle("Bestandseingruppierung")

    def update_figure(self):
        self.axes.bar(self.x, self.y)
        #self.y = np.roll(self.y,-1)
        #self.draw()
        self.canvas.draw()
    def on_button_press_event(self, event):
        print('button={}, x={}, y={}, xdata={}, ydata={}'
            .format(event.button, event.x, event.y, event.xdata, event.ydata))

       if self.im:
                message = str(self.im.get_cursor_data(event))
                delay = 1000
                w = self.lb.fontMetrics().width(message)
                self.lb.resize(w, self.lb.size().height())
                self.lb.setText(message)
                self.lb.move(QtGui.QCursor.pos())
                self.lb.show()
                QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(delay, self.lb.hide)




    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)

        main = Window()
        main.show()

        sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The Problem is: it is not shown any plot, even I do not get any error. I just obtain an empty [image: window].

How can I get the chart by pressing the plot bottom? I guess, I am doing some thing wrong under `def plot(self):`.

Just because of clarification: I tested the chart within a GUI generated by PyQt5 as a stand alone code, which works totally fine:

```
# FigureCanvas inherits QWidget
class MainWindow(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=4, height=3, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.hold(False)

        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        timer = QTimer(self)
        timer.timeout.connect(self.update_figure)
        timer.start(50)

        self.x  = ["BE"+s for s in[str(s) for s in [int(x) for x in datag.iloc[:,0].tolist()]]]#np.arange(0, 4*np.pi, 0.1)
        self.y  = datag.iloc[:,1].tolist()#np.sin(self.x)

        self.setWindowTitle("Best")

    def update_figure(self):
        self.axes.bar(self.x, self.y)
        #self.y = np.roll(self.y,-1)
        self.draw()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()

    mainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You have an indentation error in your plot function. Also you will need to call the `update_figure()` method afterwards in order to update your graph.

Comment: @MrLeeh: I added the stand alone part which works fine. Where should 'update_figure' be?

Comment: Put it right at the end of your plot function.

Comment: I tried in all places still the same issue :(

Comment: PyQt5 should also include PyQtChart, which makes it fairly easy to make dynamic plots. May be worth looking at as well (I've used it fairly successfully for some plotting for scientific software previously).

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, thanks but I make a mistake by calling the plot probably

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution!

I have 3 botons in this GUI as shown in the following part of the code:

```
class Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        # a figure instance to plot on
        self.figure = plt.figure()

        # this is the Canvas Widget that displays the `figure`
        # it takes the `figure` instance as a parameter to __init_
        self.im = None
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', self.on_button_press_event)

        # this is the Navigation widget
        # it takes the Canvas widget and a parent
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.plot)
        self.timer.setInterval(0)

        # Just some button connected to `plot` method
        self.button = QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.timer.start)
        self.button.setDefault(False)

        self.stop = QPushButton("Stop")
        self.stop.clicked.connect(self.timer.stop)
        self.stop.setDefault(False)

        self.exit = QPushButton('Exit')
        self.exit.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.exit.setDefault(True)
```

One has to set the time delay in `self.timer.setInterval(0)` to Zero! That is the first point.

The part `def plot(self)` should be changed as follows:

```
def plot(self):
        data=x
        self.setWindowTitle("Bestandseingruppierung")
        # instead of ax.hold(False)
        self.figure.clear()

        # create an axis
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        #fig.autofmt_xdate()
        # discards the old graph
        ax.hold(False) # deprecated, see above

        # plot data
        ax.axes.bar(data,y)
        self.canvas.draw()
```